# How to apply mask to a save image (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, save, photo, mask

My code does the following:

1. Take a picture and display it in image view. 
   [image]
2. save the image view in a custom size using cgrect in the photo gallery.
   [image]

However my problem is the mask is not be transferred to `l?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 10, y: 240.5, width: 435 , height: 435), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)`. All I want to do is save the photo with the mask.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
var screenView: UIImageView!

var image1 = UIImage(named: "w")
var image3 = UIImage(named: "w")
var image2 = UIImage(named: "w")
func cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let originalImageSize: CGSize = image.size
    let smallImageSize = CGSize(width: (originalImageSize.width + 40), height: (originalImageSize.height + 40))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(smallImageSize)
    image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
    let imageResult = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return imageResult
}
var currentImageView: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet var photoDispaly: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.currentImageView?.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true)

}
func saveImage(image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage, image3: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    screenView = UIImageView()

    let newSize = CGSize(width: 900, height: 1200)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    UIColor.black.setFill()
    UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)).fill()
    UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    let l = photoDispaly.image

    let image = photoDispaly.image

    let maskingImage = UIImage(named: "mask5")

    photoDispaly.image = maskImage(image: image!, mask: maskingImage!)
    photoDispaly.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]
    photoDispaly.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // OR .scaleAspectFill
    photoDispaly.clipsToBounds = true

    l?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 10, y: 240.5, width: 435 , height: 435), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    screenView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    self.view.addSubview(screenView)
    return newImage
}
@IBAction func takePhot(_ sender: Any) {
    self.currentImageView = self.photoDispaly
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage{
    let imageReference = image.cgImage
    let maskReference = mask.cgImage
    let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference!.width,
                            height: maskReference!.height,
                            bitsPerComponent: maskReference!.bitsPerComponent,
                            bitsPerPixel: maskReference!.bitsPerPixel,
                            bytesPerRow: maskReference!.bytesPerRow,
                            provider: maskReference!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)
    let maskedReference = imageReference!.masking(imageMask!)
    let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage:maskedReference!)
    return maskedImage
}


func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
          return
    } else {
        return
    }
}


@IBAction func savePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let croppedImage = cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: image2!),
        let combinedImage = saveImage(image1: image1!, image2: croppedImage, image3: croppedImage) else {

            return
    }

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combinedImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

}}
```

Comment: Quick tip: add comments to your code to help other people understand what it's supposed to do (can also help you understand what's *not* doing what you think it should do). Also, it would help if you showed the "mask" image you are trying to use, and what you are expecting the result to be.

Comment: I figured it out the code has to be in the func cropImageIntoQuarterSquare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
var screenView: UIImageView!

var image1 = UIImage(named: "w")
var image3 = UIImage(named: "w")
var image2 = UIImage(named: "w")
func cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    let image = photoDispaly.image

    let maskingImage = UIImage(named: "mask5")



    photoDispaly.image = maskImage(image: image!, mask: maskingImage!)
    photoDispaly.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]
    photoDispaly.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // OR .scaleAspectFill
    photoDispaly.clipsToBounds = true


    let originalImageSize: CGSize = image!.size
    let smallImageSize = CGSize(width: (originalImageSize.width + 40), height: (originalImageSize.height + 40))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(smallImageSize)
    image?.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
    let imageResult = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return imageResult
}
var currentImageView: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet var photoDispaly: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.currentImageView?.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true)

}


func saveImage(image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage, image3: UIImage) -> UIImage? {



    screenView = UIImageView()

    let newSize = CGSize(width: 900, height: 1200)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    UIColor.black.setFill()
    UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)).fill()
    UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()



    let l = photoDispaly.image






      l?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 10, y: 240.5, width: 435 , height: 435), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)




    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    screenView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

    self.view.addSubview(screenView)
    return newImage
}
@IBAction func takePhot(_ sender: Any) {
    self.currentImageView = self.photoDispaly
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self




        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}

func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage{
    let imageReference = image.cgImage
    let maskReference = mask.cgImage
    let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference!.width,
                            height: maskReference!.height,
                            bitsPerComponent: maskReference!.bitsPerComponent,
                            bitsPerPixel: maskReference!.bitsPerPixel,
                            bytesPerRow: maskReference!.bytesPerRow,
                            provider: maskReference!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)
    let maskedReference = imageReference!.masking(imageMask!)
    let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage:maskedReference!)
    return maskedImage
}



func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
            return
    } else {
        return

    }}


@IBAction func savePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let croppedImage = cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: image1!),
        let combinedImage = saveImage(image1: image1!, image2: croppedImage, image3: croppedImage)




        else {

            return
    }

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combinedImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }}
```